# How to put Latin in a BibLaTeX entry?

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, languages

If I want to produce a referece like this in my bibliography:

```
Boncompagni, Baldassarre. Tre scritti inediti di Leonardo 
Pisano. — Firenze : Tipografia Galileiana, 1854. — 122 p. (in Lat.)
```

Do I use "Latin" or "langlatin" as my language? Because in biblatex manual it says it's either a literal or a key.

Where does it say that I need to add "lang" prefix to the language? And why do i need it there?

In the manual it says:

```
 If localization keys are used, the preﬁx lang is omissible.
```

What are the **localization keys**?

This is very confusing - please help!

Comment: Nope, see: http://www.amazon.com/Scritti-Inediti-Leonardo-Pisano-Latin/dp/1149252413

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking at `biblatex-examples.bib`, I see that the field is used as

```
language      = {langlatin and langgerman},
```

whereas other 'language' fields also show items such as

```
origlanguage      = {german},
```

I'd therefore suggest that you use either `lang<key>` or `<literal>`, so in your case either `langlatin` or `Latin` would be correct.

(The idea is that `langlatin` is picked up automatically to be replaced by whatever has been defined as the 'localised' string here. On the other hand 'Latin' is treated as a literal and is typeset as-is.)

Comment: @drozzy: Sorry, I meant that _`origlanguage`_ only recognises keys, while `language` is 'flexible'.