# language in latex and in particular in biblatex

Tags: bibtex, languages, babel

I write my thesis in French but some of my references are in German, English, and French. I use babel for the French but English titles are in French format! My document is this one:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,draft]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english,francais]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\begin{document}
Mandelbrot~\cite{mandelbrot_77}    
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{biblio}
\end{document}
```

where my bib file is:

```
@book{mandelbrot_77,
title={Fractals: Form, Chance, and Dimension},
author={Mandelbrot, B.B.},
year={1977},
hyphenation={English}
}
```

The result is that there is a space before ":" in the English title. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: You should have a look at this: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/81655/punctuation-in-bibliography-with-multiple-languages

Comment: Thank you but the solution proposed does not compile!

Comment: Also this : http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/16624/language-in-biblatex

Comment: Have you tried also the solution proposed by egreg on the same question?